# Applying a WHERE clause to laravel return scopes

Tags: php, laravel

I have a scope on one of my laravel models to return data related to a model contained in another table:

```
public function scopeWithShortlistedApplications($query)
{
    $query->with('shortlisted_applications:shift_id,user_id,shortlisted');
}
```

Here, shortlisted_applications is the relationship and refers to a table called shift_user which has the Application model attached to it, defined as follows.

```
public function shortlisted_applications() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Application::class, 'shift_id');
}
```

What I want to do, is put a simple WHERE clause on the scope, so that it only returns instances where the "shortlisted" field is equal to 1 (this is a boolean value). I tried the following two techniques, but to not avail:

```
public function scopeWithShortlistedApplications($query)
{
    $query->with('shortlisted_applications:shift_id,user_id,shortlisted')
        ->whereRaw('SELECT shortlisted from shift_user WHERE shift_id = "' . $this->id '"', 1);
}
```

and

```
public function scopeWithShortlistedApplications($query)
{
    $query->with('shortlisted_applications:shift_id,user_id,shortlisted')
        ->where('shift_user.shortlisted', 1);
}
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this in the scope function?

Comment: do you want to constrain the eager loading or you want to restrict the main result set based on the existence of the relation with the conditions you want?

Comment: I want to contrain the result set based on the value of the "shortlisted" field. Aka, it should not load values where shortlisted = 0

Comment: "load" means eager load which is just constraining the eager load, but has no effect on the main result set (the model the scope is actually on) .. you want to restrict the result set of the main model (the one where the scope exists) based on a condition of a relationship?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the nomenclature, but I basically need to get results from the "shift_user" table, because that is where the "shortlisted" field lives, and the results I get from there should be restricted to where "shortlisted" = 1. The model I'm using this scope on has the "shifts" table and there is a relationship with the "shift_user" table.

Comment: okay sounds like an eager load constraint ... https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads   just follow those examples and you should be fine

Comment: I tried these like in the examples above, but I don't know how to reference the "shortlisted" field in the "shift_user" table in the ->where function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager loading constraints should be able to do it for you:

```
...->with(['shortlisted_applications' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('shortlisted', 1);
}]);
```

This would still load the main result set but only eager load the relationship for those records if they have `shortlisted == 1`.

Comment: Perfect thanks, how would you limit the columns returned here? I used to do "shortlisted_applications:column,column,column", but that won't work here.

Comment: you can just add a select statement to restrict it (`$query` is a builder so you can add the select onto it) ... just make sure to select any columns needed for the relationship (foreign keys, id fields, etc ...) that way Eloquent can match up the children to the parents after it loads the relationship